# How can I make an address in the address bar appear differently?

Tags: javascript, web

I have a DNS, and each computer has a website to make different folders / documents accessible in a different way than just browsing to that computer. For example, \Media takes me to the media servers pages (Music, Movies, etc.), and  \Aurora takes me to the media server's website. Instead of it displaying "Aurora" in the address bar, however, I would like to use a script to replace it with "Aurora - Media Server Website, (server information)." I would really like to learn this method, I tried to look somewhere and it mentioned JavaScript would probably be the easiest way to do this. This would be helpful if I actually knew JavaScript =p If there is an easier way to do this, that would also be much appreciated =]

In a nutshell, I want the address of a website, //Aurora, hosted on a local DNS server to appear as "Aurora - Media Server Website (server information)." What would be a possible way to implement this?

Comment: Address bar wasn't made for this. Can't you just change window title?

Comment: I know it wasn't made for this, but I know it is possible somehow.. I'd rather just learn how to set the address bar to the server information, and keep the actual page title at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the replaceState method of window.history in JavaScript like so:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', url);
```

(params are:  data (object), title (string), url (string));

I do it all the time to modify the URL, to remove the query string when using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the hostname then you have to change the DNS so that the machine gets the name you want. You can't use spaces or parenthesis in hostnames though.

The closest you can come with JS is the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which only lets you modify the local part of the URI.

Comment: I do not want to change the host name, I just want it to display additional information in the address bar. The history API looks kind of promising, though.

Comment: @ekaj — Your example is of changing the hostname. Don't do this. The page title exists for this purpose.

Comment: I use the history API, works quite well with Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I am not wanting to change the host name. I wouldn't like to type //Aurora - Media Server Website - ETC. every time I want to go there

Comment: @ekaj — All the more reason to not mess with the address bar. The whole point of it is that it contains the URI that people visit (and bookmark, and copy/paste, and read out to people). If you want a title, use a `<title>`.

Comment: The point of the question was to make a simple script that would go to //Aurora when prompted and then display additional information through the address bar using JavaScript, not to change the host name or anything else.

Comment: @ekaj — You can't display additional information in it. Period. You can fake it by changing the address (this is a stupid thing to do). To change the address in the way closest to your example you have to change the host name.

Comment: I know it is possible, because I have read in various places that this occurs in phishing often. I would just like to know how to adapt it to my purpose.

Comment: @ekaj — No, it isn't possible, that kind of phishing attack works by customising the hostname. (To something like `www.yourbank.com.sessionid234uituiouiwoeuioufiowuiofuiwoufioeiouio.example.com`)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the contents of the address bar due to security reasons (Phishing websites would exploit this heavily).

I would suggest simply changing the title of the page.

```
<title>Title goes here</title>
```

If you want to change it using javascript (for some reason) you can do this:

```
document.title = "The new title goes here.";
```